# C - opendir() return "No such file or directory"

Tags: c, pointers, directory

I am trying open dir and read files inside it .

but the function opendir() returns always "No such file or directory",
and when I put the the path it's working .

**Working:**

```
if (!(dir = opendir("/home/user/workspace/OS-Ex2Files/students/"))){
    perror(dir);
    return;
}
```

**Not working:**

```
printf(dirPath); // prints  /home/user/workspace/OS-Ex2Files/students/
if (!(dir = opendir(dirPath))){
    perror(dir);
    return;
}
```

dirPath is a char* .

Can you please explain me why the second option is not working?

Comment: Are you sure there's no superfluous whitespace in `dirPath`?  Can you try checking with `strcmp` to be sure?

Comment: srtcmp returned that the strings are not equals , but not because superfluous whitespace.

@user3121023 - if was filled using getline (from a FILE) - and you answer solved the problem! now its working

Comment: Well, then you have found your issue :)

Comment: If `printf(dirPath);` prints a newline, then that's the problem.  You shouldn't use that; you should write `printf("dirPath = [%s]\n",dirPath);` which is both safer (file names containing `%` would send `printf()` into a tizzy) and makes it easier to see embedded newlines or carriage returns because of the `[` and `]` markers surrounding the string.

Comment: FIY in C the newline character `\n` is considered a whitespace.

Comment: I'm not having any problems in my own implementation; can you show us how you're setting the `dirPath` variable?

Comment: @Jose - dirPath filled by getline() from a file - getline(&dirPath,&dirlen,file) and that is why its ending with "\n"